# Did backbone collection automatically parse the loaded data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Try to use backbone collection to initialize grabbing the json data, but turns out the data is empty. 
Does backbone collection automatically parse the json data to the model or we have to manually parse it?

```
 var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    title:"",
    isbn:"",
    img:""  
 });

 var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Book,
    url:'latest.json',
    // parse:function(data){
    //  console.log(data);
    // },       
    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    }
 });
```

Edited to add in my sample json, I validate with jsonlint.com.

```
[
    {"title":"American Pie","isbn":"345354356","img":"/image/pie.png"},
    {"title":"Long Tails","isbn":"567575576g","img":"/image/long_tails.png"},
    {"title":"Pirates","isbn":"567575765","img":"/image/pirates.png"}
]
```

Added in JSFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/5E3Nc/14/

Comment: You don't need to manually parse the data if the data if in the correct format. How does your `latest.json` response look like?

Comment: Also check in your browser's console to see if the url requested is correct I miss a `/` in the beginning of this `url`.

Comment: @fguillen. Thanks for reply. I check my browser console, and it loads properly. But when I dump the book.toJSON(), it return an [], looks like it did not parse it properly.

Comment: Of-topic: beware that the lines as `title:""` are not a proper way to initialize default **attributes** of a Model. Use [Model.defaults](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-defaults) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure these work first

- No Script errors ( Inspect them in javascript console)
- Collection.fetch makes a request to correct url ( see resources section in Chrome web inspector)
- Check that response `mime/type` is right "application/json" and Server indeed serves JSON string
- Make sure the JSON response is **well formed** ( I had this problem . It must be a array and not a object ex : `[{},{},{},{}]`)
- Lastly refresh from the server ( clear the cache)

#### Update

Here is a JsFiddle to demonstrate the use http://jsfiddle.net/5E3Nc/16/

**note:** Parse must explicitly be written only when custom response is sent from server from which you want to build the models collection

by the way, i notices you did this

```
initialize:function(){
  this.fetch();
}
```

this won't work. You are expected to use the collection outside of the collection itself
for example

```
var col = Backbone.Collection.extend({url:"data.json"});
var instance = new col({model:Tweet});
instance.fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested it. But did not works either. Maybe I will try with a jsfiddle.

Comment: I want to add that you can add a `success` and `error` callbacks to your `fetch()` call to see if something is there like: `instance.fetch({ error: function(){ console.log( "ERROR" ); } });`

Comment: @TonyMocha How do you say it did not work. Please check `instance.models` to see if it contains the models from the server #http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-models

Comment: @Deeptechtons not sure I understand it well. Here's the jsfiddle I did for trying to display the object.http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/5E3Nc/14/

Comment: @TonyMocha Well it happens. People new to Backbone world are often get confused. Here is a JS Fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/5E3Nc/16/ note that for ajax request `echo/json/` means replace `json` with the response to be sent for ajax requests

Comment: @Deeptechtons. If I fetched JSON data from variable than ajax, it is working fine. But my scenario is I have to load the JSON data externally, any chance to make it work?