# can't fetch properly collection using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Please read till the end (i make a reference to console.log at the end)

the model:

```
// Spot model:
define([
  'jquery',    
  'underscore',
  'backbone'  
], function($, _, Backbone){
    var Spot = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function(){
            if (this.get('id') !== null){
                return '/spot/' + this.get('id');
            }
            return '/spots';
        },
        idAttribute: "id",
        defaults: {
            id: null,
            details:{
                name: "school",
                type: 4,
                rank: 3,
                comment: null
            },
            location:{
                    address: '',
                    lat: 70.345,
                    lng: 90.123
            },
            user:{
                id: 12345,
                name: "magneto"
            }
        },
        parse: function(response){
        /*  var attrs = {
                details: {},
                location: {},
                user: {}
            };
            attrs.id = response.id;

            attrs.details.name = response.details.name;
            attrs.details.type = response.details.type;
            attrs.details.rank = response.details.rank;
            attrs.location.lat = response.location.lat;
            attrs.location.lng = response.location.lng;
            return attrs; */
        }
    });
    return Spot;
});
```

the collection:

```
// Spots collection:
define([
  'jquery',    
  'underscore',
  'backbone',  
  'models/Spot'
], function($, _, Backbone,spot_model){
    var Spots = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: spot_model,
        url:
            function() {
            return '/projects/FE/spots';
          },
        parse: function(response){
    /*      var parsed = [],
              key;

          _.each(response, function (value) {
              parsed.push(value);
          }, this);

          return parsed;*/
        },
      comparator: function(spot){
        return spot.rank;
      }
    });
    return Spots;
});
```

the view:

```
// inside our view named: SpotsView
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'mustache',
  'icanhaz',
  'views/spots/Spot',
  'collections/Spots',
  'text!../../../../templates/spots/spots.mustache!strip',
], function($,
            _,
            Backbone,
            mustache,
            ich,
            SpotView,
            Spots,
            SpotsTemplate){
  var SpotsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //el: $("#container"),
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize: function(){

      console.log('initialize view');
      console.log(this.collection);
      _.bindAll(this,'render');

    },
    render: function(){
      console.log(this.collection);
      console.log('length: ' + this.collection.length);
      console.log('models: ' + this.collection.models);

      _.each(this.collection.models, function (spot) {
            $(this.el).append(new SpotView({model:spot}).render().el);
        }, this);
      return this;
    }
  });
  return SpotsView;
});
```

inside our app.js

```
   var spots = new Spots({model: Spot}),
        spotsview;


    spots.reset();
    console.log(spots.fetch());
    console.log('spots:');
    console.log(spots.length);
    console.log(spots);
    spotsview = new SpotsView({collection: spots});
```

Server outputs

```
// SERVER output(s) i tried:
{"id": 666,"details":{"name": "mark","type":4,"rank":3.1,"comment":"nothing"},"location":{"lat":70.123,"lng":90.321,"address":"5th avenue"},"user":{"id":333,"name":"wolverine"}}

// another one i tried:
[{"id": 666,"details":{"name": "mark","type":4,"rank":3.1,"comment":"nothing"},"location":{"lat":70.123,"lng":90.321,"address":"5th avenue"},"user":{"id":333,"name":"wolverine"}}]

// another one:
[{"id":"55","details":{"name":"Dan","type":"6","rank":"-9.9","comment":"myEx"},"location":{"lat":"40.780346","lng":"-73.957657","address":"78, West 86th Stree"}},{"id":"57","details":{"name":"Ron","type":"6","rank":"3.0","comment":"Butch"},"location":{"lat":"40.715569","lng":"-73.832428","address":"1344 Queens Boulevard"}},{"id":"58","details":{"name":"Monk's","type":"11","rank":"9.5","comment":"yesss"},"location":{"lat":"40.805443","lng":"-73.965561","address":"112th and broadway "}}]




// without using "parse" method in the collection and in the model (they are commented) i get:
d
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
length: 0
models: Array[0]
__proto__: x

// when not commented (parse in both collection and model) i get:
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
length: 6
models: Array[6]
__proto__: x

// despite it says 6, in the view you can see there are lines:
//console.log(this.collection);  <--- returns the abovee
//console.log('length: ' + this.collection.length); <-- returns 0
//console.log('models: ' + this.collection.models); <--- none
```

I also tried removing all properties defenitions from the model. Still didn't work.
The return value content type is: application/json (verified) and is valid json.

I've read:
[Backbonejs collection length always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159360/backbonejs-collection-length-always-zero)

but inspite of console.log , showing 0 length , also:

```
for(var i=0; i< this.collection.length; i++){
        console.log(this.collection.get(i));
}
```

doens't work!

also i've read
[Did backbone collection automatically parse the loaded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427764/did-backbone-collection-automatically-parse-the-loaded-data)

Thanks a lot

Update:
I've probably solved it: i've removed even the "parse" declarations from the model and the collection and It worked: length: 6 SpotsView.js models: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] Either way i would like to know the proper use , if i did right and HOW to use PARSE in both situations the right way (collection and model wise), what do you return in both (!). Tnx

Comment: I've probably solved it: i've removed even the "parse" declarations from the model and the collection and It worked:
length: 6 SpotsView.js
models: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 

Either way i would like to know the proper use , if i did right and HOW to use PARSE in both situations the right way (collection and model wise), what do you return in both (!).

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.fetch` is an asynchronous operation, therefore when you fetch a collection, the ajax call will be sent and then your code will continue being run just like nothing happened.

```
spots.reset(); // emptied your collections

console.log(spots.fetch()); // fetch your collection (why is this inside a console.log???)

console.log('spots:'); // log some text, this will be executed right after your fetch call has been made

console.log(spots.length); // here the fetch call probably hasn't returned yet, so returns 0

console.log(spots); // same as above, so returns an empty collection

spotsview = new SpotsView({collection: spots}); // the collection might or might not get populated by the time you get to rendering so there is probably variation from program run to another
```

So how to fix this? In the view bind the render function to the collection's reset event (launched after each successful fetch or forced reset). This way the view will render only when it has something to show.

```
// view's initialize method
initialize: function() {
  ...
  this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
  ...
}
```

Comment: jakee: tnx for the input, i've actually did bind the view of the collection with the this.collection.bind('all',this.render); when playing. Either way, you can see above, i was able to solve the problem. But about using parse in both cases (model and collection is still a mystery). Thank you.